# boost async sockets and boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-thread

I writing TCP client which should be able to send and receive data at the same time.
Could you tell me how should I call `async_send` and `async_receive` is separate threads?

In the other words how to call

```
m_Socket.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(txBuf.c_str(), txBuf.length()+1),
    boost::bind(&TCPClient::sendingHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

m_Socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(rxBuf, maxBufLen),
    boost::bind(&TCPClient::sendingHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

in

```
boost::thread receivingThread(boost::bind(...));
boost::thread sendingThread(boost::bind(...));
```

And will it work correctly if I call `async_send`  or `async_receive` again inside handlers? I need an infinitive loop for sending/receivind data.

Comment: You don't need separate threads for simultaneous sending/receiving. Just call `async_send` and `async_receive`, in the same thread, and the `io_service` will take or it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main idea is - send and receive in recursion inside`TCPClient::sendingHandler/receivingHandler` on the 2 `io_service's`. This `io_service's` are called inside 2 threads -

```
boost::thread receivingThread(boost::bind(...));
boost::thread sendingThread(boost::bind(...));
```

This idea is clearly seen in this [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp). The only difference that you have to call and use 2 separate `io_service's`.

Another option is 1 `io_service` and multiply threads calling `io_service::run`. But then you have to use `boost::asio::strand` far thread safety:

```
boost::asio::strand* _strand = new boost::asio::strand(io);
//then use it in handlers
boost::asio::async_read(*socket, 
                    boost::asio::buffer(msg.data(), result.size),
                    (*_strand).wrap(
                    boost::bind(&ConnectionInterface::parsePacket, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
```

Comment: I need to create 2 `io_service`. In easch `io_service` i need to use recursion call `async_recieve(boost::bind(recievingHandler))` / `async_send(boost::bind(sendingHandler))`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, look at tutorial that i linked

Comment: Yep, tutorial is clear. But using 2 `io_service` is not clear. Using 2 `io_service` means creating 2 sockets, isn't it? But I would like to find the soulution with async socket. I think using 2 async sockets without io conflicts is not reasonable. Could you please explain it to me?